# How to add line breaks after each comma of a csv file?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, line

I have a csv - file like this:

```
1.149, 1.328, 1.420, 1.148
```

and that's my current code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("right.csv")
```

Python works on columns and rows for output.
But I would like to have such an output:

```
1.149,
1.328, 
1.420, 
1.148
```

I need it that way, because afterwards I want to know how much data is in the CSV file and work with it. But now it just tells me that I have one row and 4 column.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple lines in the input?

Comment: Do you want to keep the commas at the end of all lines except the last one? What in the case of multiple lines?

Comment: About your last edit: is your final goal to find out how much data there is in your CSV file? What about number of lines times number of columns, then?

Comment: Actually, my CSV file should look like this: all values among each other and  a comma after each value

But in my CSV file, the values are all in a row instead of under each other. In the end I want to do some calculations with these values. But for that I need to have the values among each other.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get the meaning of your last comment. Also, what looks like your current expected output, if you use the comma as separator, will be a CSV with two columns (the second containing an empty string) for all rows but the last, which will contain only one. Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, there is only one row of data like the one you had shown as an example:

```
1.149, 1.328, 1.420, 1.148
```

You can replace the white space with a new line `\n`.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("right.csv")
print(df.replace(", ", ",\n"))
```

Which will give you the result you are expecting according to my understanding:

```
1.149,
1.328,
1.420,
1.148
```

Comment: The problem is, that there are more row's. I have only shown an excerpt.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but if you simply want to know the number of fields, count the commas and newlines!

This might only be approximate, as it'll depend on how consistent your input is

```py
count = 0
with open("path/source.csv") as fh:
    for line in fh:  # iterate over lines
        if not line:
            continue
        count += 1  # each line is a new field
        count += line.count(",")
```

Otherwise, perhaps you are looking to [Transpose (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) the dataframe

[image]

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
>>> df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1.149,  1.328,  1.420,  1.148]
Index: []
>>> df.T
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [1.149,  1.328,  1.420,  1.148]
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b': [3,4]})
>>> df2
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
>>> df2.T
   0  1
a  1  2
b  3  4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("right.csv")
for column in df:
    index = str(df[column]).find('1')
    print(str(df[column])[index:index+5])
```

Comment: What is this about the '1'?

Comment: Since all of your strings start with the number '1' I search for it in the string and then create a new variable that takes all characters behind it with 5 spaces. then you print each variable in loop.